# Class 'App' not found in app.php file, Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

I´m trying to get the local value in the file `app/config/app.php` using the `App::getLocale()` method:

```
'locale' => App::getLocale(),
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Class 'App' not found
```

How can I use this method in the `app.php` config file?

Answer (score 1):

The `App` class is not yet loaded when the `app/config` files are loaded.

You can use `Config::get('app.locale')` instead, but in this case it isn't going to work - you're trying to set the `locale` value to the app's locale, but the app's locale is whatever you set `locale` to be. It's circular.

Comment: Nope, this report me .> Class 'Config' not found

Comment: @RP_morales I have no trouble using the Config class in my config files. That said, what you're trying to do doesn't make sense. See my edit.